# Environment Variables undefined NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables, next.js

I want to set a simple login with just a password in .env but when I try to use this variable it takes undefined.

Code:

.env.local

```
REACT_APP_PASS_TOKEN=d61b100cacb60432f97b39b70d9ff5067242a5d9da1acad54738fc65562b8e1b
```

login.js

(First log prints value correctly but second one does not)

```
const pass = process.env.REACT_APP_PASS_TOKEN


console.log(`KEY: ${pass}`)

const handleLogin = () => {
    console.log(`KEY: ${pass}`)
  }
```

Comment: Change prefix `REACT_APP_` to `NEXT_PUBLIC_`: [Nextjs ENV docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser)

Comment: It works!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some mechanism to manage this process. Try with dotenv.
Simply install this using

```
npm i dotenv
```

After that you need to attach this module to your main app.

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

Try to define variable and assign API key to it.

```
const psw = process.env.REACT_APP_PASS_TOKEN;
```

Then just swap var names.
In result should to looks like:

.env

```
REACT_APP_PASS_TOKEN=d61b100cacb60432f97b39b70d9ff5067242a5d9da1acad54738fc65562b8e1b
```

login.js

```
const pass = process.env.REACT_APP_PASS_TOKEN;
require("dotenv").config();

const psw = process.env.REACT_APP_PASS_TOKEN;

console.log(`KEY: ${psw}`);

const handleLogin = () => {
  console.log(`KEY: ${psw}`);
};

handleLogin();
```